# Assigning elements from returned array where index is 1 or higher

Tags: javascript, return, multiple-return-values

Given is a function, that returns an array with (n) elements.
I want to assign these return values, but not the first one.

```
// match returns ["abc123","abc","123"] here  
[ foo, bar ] = "abc123".match(/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/);
```

Now I've got

```
foo = "abc123"
bar = "abc"
```

But my intention had been

```
foo = "abc"
bar = "123"
```

In other languages you can do stuff like

```
//pseudocode  
[_,foo,bar] = "abc123".match(/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/);
```

To archive this, but how is it done in JS?

Surely, one could do

```
[garbage,foo,bar] = "abc123".match(/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/);
garbage = undefined;
```

.. but,.. urgh..

Comment: Try `var [foo, bar] = ...`

Comment: Fixes an mistake I made in initial post, but isn't a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using ES6 (ECMAScript 2015, the latest version of JavaScript). If so, your pseudocode was really close, you just don't even need a variable name in the first position, you can just leave it off entirely:

```
[ , foo, bar] = "abc123".match(/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/);
```

Note the leading comma. That stores the value from index 1 in `foo` and the value from index 2 in `bar`.

[Live Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=let%20foo%2C%20bar%3B%0A%5B%20%2C%20foo%2C%20bar%5D%20%3D%20%22abc123%22.match(%2F(%5Ba-z%5D*)(%5B0-9%5D*)%2F)%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22foo%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20foo)%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22bar%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20bar)%3B) on Babel's REPL

You can do that at any point in the sequence on the left. For instance, let's pretend that you wanted `foo` to be the value from 0 and `bar` to be the value from 2:

```
// Different from what the question asks, an example
// of grabbing index 0 and index 2
[foo, , bar] = "abc123".match(/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/);
```

Since we didn't put anything in the second position on the left, it's skipped during the deconstructing assignment.

Comment: Chrome Version 45.0.2454.93 m (64-bit) (latest @17.09.2015-08:28CET)
>> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,(…) <<

Is this the ES6 Issue u meant?

Comment: Life Example is throwing more questions than answers for me, however, question is answered.

Comment: @Sempie: There is no browser in the wild that supports even a majority of ES6 yet. If you're using ES6, you must (currently) be using a transpiler. [More info here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#destructuring). Firefox manages part of it, but it'll be several months before even actively-improved engines like SpiderMonkey (in FF) and V8 (in Chrome) catch up to the specification. For instance, the above fails in Firefox unless it's part of a variable declaration (e.g., `var [, foo, bar] = ...`), even though it should work without the `var`. They're working on it... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to extract a subsequence of the array.

```
[foo, bar] = "abc123".match(/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/).slice(1);
```

Note that this assignment of multiple variables is an EcmaScript 6 feature, so it won't work on older browsers. The syntax requires that they be enclosed in array brackets (you're assigning an array of variables from an array of values).